# How do I set up apache with multiple sites?

Tags: lamp

Can I have help with making multiple site working with Apache (LAMP) on ubuntu 12.04 desktop ed. I pointed the apache2 to a home directory with my new sites which were enabled, but the browser is only displaying the default website that come with the apache2 installation. 
thx

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Can you explain how you pointed Apache to your home directory? Also, your question is a bit vague. Can you clarify what you're trying to do more specifically?

Comment: You need read about **Virtual Hosts** or **userdir** -  it depends what you really need. Take a look on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/httpd.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install LAMP on ubuntu 12.04 [how to configure apache linux](http://tuxtweaks.com/2009/07/how-to-configure-apache-linux/) not the one on the ubuntu wiki ApacheMysqlPhp which seems to be a bit outdated since you can ow do the whole installation with:

> sudo apt-get install lamp-server^

Now my problem was after creating two news web sites directories called site1 and site2 and enabling them in apache2, I had to point apache2 to their location by editing the etc/hosts file.
this was my mistake or what was not working:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost
>
> 127.0.0.1 localhost site1
>
> 127.0.0.1 localhost site2

The solution was to point my new sites directories in one line like this:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost site1 site2

Answer (score 0):

As us3r indicated in the comment, you need to read the [Ubuntu Serve Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/httpd.html) that covers this. Under Configurations > Basic Settings you'll find the instructions to:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/mynewsite
```

and then edit several files to get that site up and running. In other words, use the default Apache site configuration to create one for each site you want to host, then tweak that file to specify all the needed directives(*ServerAdmin*, *ServerName*, *Listen* ports, etc.) for *mynewsite*.

The guide is very well done, and if you take you time and work through it step-by-step, you should be up and running with multiple sites fairly soon.

**P.S.** - Hopefully it goes without saying, but please replace *mynewsite* with the actual name of the site you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had issues when adding new sites to 127.0.0.1 where all the config files were setup correctly and the cache cleared but one of the new sites was not working. To fix it I had to disable all of the other sites using the terminal command a2dissite *sitename* first then enable the new site using a2ensite *sitename*, restart the server and it worked.